# Is there any alternative for thread_local! in substrate?

Tags: polkadot, pallet, substrate-node-template, storage

I what to use `thread_local!` in substrate.
I aware about Storage ;)

I want to store temporary data for unit tests. without thread local it does not work property.

```
thread_local! {
    static COINS: RefCell<Vec<Data>> = RefCell::new(vec![]);
}
```

But is there any alternative for `thread_local!` in substrate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But is there any alternative for thread_local! in substrate?

There is not really a replacement. However, you can use [`frame_support::parameter_types!`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/cba59778aa5207b11f7513e5cbb127ea47dd8924/frame/support/src/lib.rs#L213-L283) to create some thread_local that directly implements `Get`:

```
parameter_types! {
    static Value: u32 = 10;
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
Value::set(100);
Value::get();
```

Or you can also directly pass `Value` to some `Config` trait that expects a type that implements `Get<u32>`. Then you can use this in your test to change the value as you like.